# Could not get downloaded items in Chrome 80

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Before Chrome 80 (79.0.3945.130), you could get all downloaded items in Chrome by accessing to [chrome://downloads/](http://chrome://downloads/) and get downloaded items from global variable `downloads`.

```
var items = downloads.Manager.get().items_;
```

[image]

But it seems that since version 80, Google has hidden the `Manager` properties from the `downloads` variable, so I could not get downloaded items anymore.

[image]

I would appreciate it if you could tell me any idea about the new way to get downloaded items. (bow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return document.querySelector('downloads-manager')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList')
  .items.filter(e => e.state === 'COMPLETE')
  .map(e => e.filePath || e.file_path || e.fileUrl || e.file_url);
```

Comment: self.driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList').items.filter(e => e.state === 'COMPLETE').map(e => e.filePath || e.file_path || e.fileUrl || e.file_url);")

Comment: Hi @Itay Levy, this is exactly what I want, it doesn't only work well in 80 but also on old version. You save my day. Very nice contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Not working on ***Google Chrome Version 119*** `e => e.state === 'COMPLETE'`

**Use this:**

```
return document.querySelector('downloads-manager')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList')
  .items.filter(e => e.state == '2')
  .map(e => e.filePath || e.file_path || e.fileUrl || e.file_url);
```